# How to modify last two characters of a string depending on a condition using Perl

Tags: string, perl, substring

I have string which need to checked for last two characters. If the last two characters are found matching with my requirement, i need to truncate the string, otherwise leave the string as it is. I know it can be done using control conditions, but i want to know if there is any single statement in perl that could actually achieve this. Also suggest any better ways of doing this.

Example:

```
$str = "Hello";
```

so if last two characters are say "tr", i want to truncate the string, but in this case we need to leave the string as original, as the last characters are not "tr"

Answer (score 6):

Perl's substitution operator `s///`  is ideal here. `\z` matches end of string, but not end of line.

```
$str =~ s/tr\z//;
```